# Why does a class not need the forward declaration of a function defined later than its use?

Tags: c++

Prog1 :

```
class A{
public:
    void test_a(){
        b();//No need for forward declaration
    }
    void b(){
     //Do something
    }
}
```

Prog2:

```
void a();//forward declaration, else failure
int main(){
   a();
   return 0;
}

void a(){
//Do something
}
```

As we can see that the second program will fail without the forward declaration.

Why does the first one not fail?

Comment: Essentially, because that's what the standard specifies in rules for name lookup.   Definition (implementation) of a class member function requires the compiler to have visibility of the entire class definition - which includes the declaration (but not necessarily the definition) of all member functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the rule of [name lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup#Member_function_definition) is different for member functions:

(emphasis mine)

> For a name used inside a member function body, a default argument of a member function, an exception specification of a member function, a default member initializer`, a contract condition of a member function (since C++20)`, or a nested class definition (including names of the bases from which the nested class is derived), the scopes searched are the same as in class definition, except that **the entire scope of the class is considered, not just the part prior to the declaration that uses the name**.

Then there's no need of forward declaration for a member function to be called from another one.